# Can't remove jar from Web App Library

Tags: eclipse, configuration, java, buildpath

How can I remove the jars in my Web App Library?

I manually added a couple jars to the web app library. 
My program is now pitching a fit so I clearly need to remove them.

However, when I go to the Build Path, the "Remove" is greyed out. 
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A project's Web App Library is composed automatically by Eclipse from any JARs on the project path, `<project-name>/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`. JARs reach that location:

1. after the project is created (of course, since the project file system begins to exist only then)
2. by the user's hand.

So, you can edit the Web App library by adding / deleting jars under `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

More details on [Web App libraries](http://www.javahotchocolate.com/tutorials/web-jars.html) can be found here.

Comment: When I click on Edit, I only have one option (my project) and then can only click Finish. When I do that, nothing changes.

Comment: @AllieCat I have edited my answer with link to a guide on Web App libraries. That link might help you..

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out - sorry to bother everyone.

Go to the jar in the Project Explorer, right click and Delete.

[image: Deleting jar in Web App Library]

Comment: that delete button is also disabled.

Answer (score 5):

After delete some libs, delete Webapp libs in Build Path then close and open Eclipse, add Webapp Libs in Build Path again. Worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was, I was trying to delete the JARs from Build Path, which I accessed through 'Project Explorer' tab. But the JARs delete option is greyed out there, as per the original question.

So I tried the same from : 'Navigator' perspective (which is deprecated). When I went to my projects build path from here, I could see the delete option.

Answer (score 0):

For Spring tools I open workspace folder **manually** ...

C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.18.0.RELEASE\JavaApp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib

and delete the jars from there!

Hooray they're gone. Doesnt look like we need an IDE neither.

Also you can try to view files in Package Explorer instead of Project Explorer...

Windows -> Show View  -> Package Explorer